# Why is the Wordpress taxonomy not registering?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am trying to create a taxonomies attached to a custom post type. The CPT is registering fine, but the taxonomy is not showing up. Eventually there will be multiple taxonomies attached.

I am getting no errors that I can see (no fatal WP errors, nothing in the browser console) but WP is not registering the taxonomy. Its like the taxonomy class isn't even there. I checked outside of WP to see if all the values are present, and they seem to be passed correctly.

Why is it not registering? Thanks for any guidance, code below...

```
class pm_createTaxonomy
{
protected $textdomain;

public function __construct($textdomain)
{
    $this -> textdomain = $textdomain;

    add_action('init', array($this, 'registerTaxonomy'));
}

public function makeTaxonomy($taxName, $singularName, $pluralName, $postTypes, $settings=array())
{
    /* Cleanup slugs just in case */
    $this -> taxName = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $taxName));
    $this -> postTypes = $postTypes;

    /* Default labels */
    $default_labels = array(
        'name'                       => __($pluralName, $this->textdomain),
        'singular_name'              => __($singularName, $this->textdomain),
        'search_items'               => __('Search ' . strtolower($pluralName), $this->textdomain),
        'poular_items'               => __('Popular ' . strtolower($pluralName), $this->textdomain),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __('Choose from most used ' . strtolower($pluralName), $this->textdomain),
        'all_items'                  => __('All ' . strtolower($pluralName), $this->textdomain),
        'parent_item'                => __('Parent ' . $singularName, $this->textdomain),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __('Parent ' . $singularName, $this->textdomain),
        'edit_item'                  => __('Edit ' . $singularName, $this->textdomain),
        'update_item'                => __('Update ' . $singularName, $this->textdomain),
        'add_new_item'               => __('Add New ' . $singularName, $this->textdomain),
        'new_item_name'              => __('New ' . $singularName, $this->textdomain),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __('Add or remove ' . strtolower($pluralName), $this->textdomain),
        'menu_name'                  => __($pluralName, $this->textdomain),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate ' . strtolower($pluralName) . ' with commas', $this->textdomain)
    );

    $default_args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'label'             => $pluralName,
        'labels'            => $default_labels,
        'public'            => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'rewrite'           => array('slug' => sanitize_title_with_dashes($pluralName)),
    );

    $this -> args = array_merge($default_args, $settings);
}

public function registerTaxonomy()
{
    register_taxonomy($this->taxName, $this->postTypes, $this->args);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked on this some more this evening and redid a couple of things. Edited the code above to reflect changes, everything is working now. Will mark as solved.